# Display object on all view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have several objects which I display throughout all of my ViewControllers.

I am wondering if there is a way to merge these objects into a single object and initialize the object from every ViewController in the project.

In essence, I am attempting to merge the objects (they are the same type and do the same thing) and make them globally accessible.

Ex.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
```

I would like to display and access this UIProgressView from all ViewControllers.

Comment: Can you create a custom view controller that acts as a container for your other view controllers and have your constant controls positioned outside its container area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put these interface elements in a UIViewController subclass and then have all of your other viewControllers inherit from that one (i.e. an abstract superclass) in this way there is only one lot of code which covers them all.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. What would be the proper way to declare the new class as a subclass to the FirstViewController, for example?

Comment: go into the .h file for each and import the header file of the intended superclass  #import "firstViewController.h"  and then just change it, where you have \@interface someViewController : UIViewController to \@interface someViewController : firstViewController